# How can I use /manload on my server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have finally figured out how to make new groups and stuff in groupmanager. I made some standard groups and went on the server to do `/manload` (reloading the GM config file)

But when I did, I got this error:

> An internal error occurred while attempting to perform this command

before it started raining. I would turn it off with `/weather clear`, and it reports another error:

> you don't  have access to that command

What is going on? It worked fine before I made one group and typed `/manload`. Now I don't have access to any command at all.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As per the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11015/4797), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10568/4797) and [What exactly is technical support?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11015/4797) only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the result of a syntax error in the GM config file. ALL of the syntax has to be correct. If it is not, you get the error you have mentioned.

If you are regularly backing up your configs, I suggest you rollback the config to the stage with the correct syntax.

However, if you are not, I would suggest looking an online guide explaining the GM syntax.

But, you have included in the question that this happened after making one group. You have made an error in the syntax of that group. Ensure that the syntax matches that of the default-generated groups.

As a last resort, you should start all over.